# get the last day' s visits google analytics

Tags: jquery, ruby, google-analytics

is possible to get last day's visits google analytics with jquery or ruby?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Gattica with good results:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataLibraries.html

although you need to be careful how recent the data is, such as if there is a few hours delay of data.